# How to get Request params in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping("book/param")
    public String bookByParam(
   @RequestParam(required = false,name = "name") String name,
   @RequestParam(required = false,name = "author") String author,
   @RequestParam(required = false,name = "genre") String genre,
   @RequestParam(required = false,name = "genre") int price, Model m
){
  List<Books> books = bookService.showSpecificBooks(name, author, genre,price);
        m.addAttribute("books", books);
        return "book";
    }
```

For the params I wrote querys so they can be null that means if i dont input anything I will get all books.

Now I have my books.html template with following implemenation:

```
<form th:action="@{book/param}" th:object="${books}" method="get">

<label for="name">name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=name th:field="name" placeholder="name">

    <label for="author">author:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=author th:name="author" placeholder="author">

    <label for="genre">genre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=genre th:name="genre" placeholder="genre">

 <label for="price">price:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id=price th:name="price" placeholder="price">
</form>
```

I would expect that I would get a List of books within the range of the submitted values and when I have no input I would get (because of my Query) all books but all I get is a TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing. I also tried to wrap the object names like this:

```
 <input type="text" id=name th:field="*{name}" placeholder="name">
```

or like this :

```
 <input type="text" id=name th:field="${name}" placeholder="name">
```

but unfortunately it did not work. Can anyone see what I am doing from.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a model object and bind that to the form instead of separate query parameters. \

```java
public class SearchParameters {

  private String name, genre, author;
  private int price;

  // getters / setters
}
```

```java
@ModelAttribute("params")
public SearchParams params() {
  return new SearchParamters ();
}

@GetMapping("book/param")
public String bookByParam(@ModelAttribute("params") SearchParamters params, Model m
){
 List<Books> books = bookService.showSpecificBooks(params.getName(), params().getAuthor(), params.getGenre(), params.getPrice());
  m.addAttribute("books", books);
  return "book";
}
```

**TIP:** You could also pass the `SearchParameters` to your `BookService` and just get the things in there. Saves you from modifying the method when you add an additional parameter, you just need to change the `SearchParameters` and the `BookService` implementation.

Now let your form use `params` as a object and refer to the fields.

```html
<form th:action="@{book/param}" th:object="${params}" method="get">

<label for="name">name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=name th:field="name" placeholder="name">

    <label for="author">author:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=author th:field="author" placeholder="author">

    <label for="genre">genre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id=genre th:field="genre" placeholder="genre">

    <label for="price">price:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id=price th:field="price" placeholder="price">
</form>
```

This should bind your form object to the thymeleaf form and you will see earlier entered data.

To show your results you need to iterate over the `books` list and show them in a table (or something else).

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>author</th><th>Genre</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
      <td th:text="${book.name}">Name</td>
      <td th:text="${book.author}">Author</td>
      <td th:text="${book.genre}">Genre</td>
      <td th:text="${book.price}">Price</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Something like the above should do.

Comment: Yes, great explanation because of its simplicity. It is like I do very often too, and it works well. Upvoted.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have another question how do I make the input parameters optional so that  when I dont input anything that it is not visble in the url?

Comment: You don't need to, the fact that something is optional on the server doesn't mean nothing will be sent from theb rowser. The browser (the client) doesn't know (much/anything) from the server apart from the URL.

Comment: normally thats right but in my example when dont input something the value is still seen like this : param/?name=&author=&price=100 and I dont want this instead I want: param/?price=100

Comment: Thats not the value that is the parameter name. It is empty and thus will not be used on the server. Unless you reimplement the URL building (form submit) using Javascript (basically rebuild what the browser already does) this isn't possible. Or stop using a GET but use a POST instead then it will be part of the body.

Comment: so there is no other way to make  <input type="text" id=name th:field="name" placeholder="name"> into an optional param so that it wont be shown in the url?

Comment: It will still appear in the URL. That has nothing to do with the fact that it is explicitly optional on the server side. Those 2 things aren't related. You can only remove them with javascript and intercept the submitting of the form.

Comment: ok thx for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

**th:field** works for entities. From what I see *name* is a request parameter. Try using **th:name**, as you do for author, genre, price.

```
 <input type="text" id=name th:name="name" placeholder="name">
```

In order to iterate through the list of books you can try doing this:

```
<tr th:each="book : ${books}"> 
   <td><span th:text="${book.name}"> Title </span></td> 
   <td><span th:text="${book.author}"> Author </span></td> 
   <td><span th:text="${book.genre}"> Genre</span></td> 
   <td><span th:text="${book.price}"> Price</span></td> 
</tr>
```

In this case, there's no need for @RequestParam since the fields can be found inside Book entity.

Comment: I changed it but when I input something and press submit nothing changes.Normally the list of books with the given paramaters should be shown, can you spot any other mistake?